# How to create a qcow2 file that is not thin provisioned?

Tags: linux, bash, kvm-virtualization, qcow2

When I do the below then the qcow2 file is less than 200KB.

```
# qemu-img create -f qcow2 /var/lib/libvirt/images/urb-dat0.qcow2 10G
# du -hsc /var/lib/libvirt/images/urb-dat0.qcow2
196K    /var/lib/libvirt/images/urb-dat0.qcow2
```

If I attach it to a KVM guest and `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/vdb: 0 MB, 197120 bytes, 385 sectors
```

**Question**

How to make a 10GB qcow2 file that is not thin provisioned?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `preallocation` option.

```
qemu-img create -o preallocation=full -f qcow2 /var/lib/libvirt/images/urb-dat0.qcow2 10G
```

Reference: https://linux.die.net/man/1/qemu-img

> Preallocation mode (allowed values: off, metadata, full). An image with preallocated metadata is initially larger but can improve performance when the image needs to grow. Full preallocation additionally writes zeros to the whole image in order to preallocate lower layers (e.g. the file system containing the image file) as well. Note that full preallocation writes to every byte of the virtual disk, so it can take a long time for large images.

Comment: That worked =) What is the purpose of the thin provisioned qcow2 file when it can't be used for a filesystem inside a guest?

Comment: @JasmineLognnes what makes you think you can't use a thin provisioned file for a guest FS?

Comment: From the output I got from `fdisk -l` and I even tried to do `mkfs.btrfs /dev/vdb` which failed.

Comment: I may have attached the qcow2 images as raw, which could explain why it didn't worked...

Answer (score 5):

An existing thin-provisioned qcow2 file can be converted to a fully allocated one like this:

```
qemu-img convert -p -f qcow2 -O qcow2 -S 0 original-file.qcow2 new-file.qcow2
```

(This is not an answer to the question but might still be of interest.)

Comment: It may be noted that this command can be quite slow. Fully allocating a 340GB disk with 11GB used data took more than 30 minutes on a modern server on a spinning disk.